# Add a new column to a data set based off of a source index in another document

Tags: mutate

new ecologist to coding and trying my best.

I am trying to add a column to my trapping data for source ID set based off another document containing all of the sources.

I want to add a source ID based off pit tag, but if that doesn't work right ear tag, and if that doesn't work left ear tag. Then for it to not throw away the data that it doesn't work for.

I am not sure where to start! Have played around with the dyplr mutate function but am very confused.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry just very new! Thank you for your reply, honestly just having trouble even knowing where to start.
Have been able to upload both docs into Rstudio and that is about it!